# Unable to catch WebApplicationException when passing incorrect Media type

Tags: java, exception, jersey

I want to catch all types of `Throwable` so that the client is not exposed to our internal stack trace in case of exceptions.

I am using `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` as follows:

```
@Provider
public class MappableContainerExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(Throwable exception)
  {
   return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("caught").build();
  }

}
```

However, when passing `Content-Type=asdfasdf`, I get the following stack trace shown to the client:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'sdfsdfdvfv'
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.clientError(HttpHelper.java:265)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:91)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:77)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getMediaType(ContainerRequest.java:651)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters(WebComponent.java:832)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:407)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'sdfsdfdvfv'
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
    javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:77)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getMediaType(ContainerRequest.java:651)
```

I want to catch this as well so that the client is shown pretty JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a borderline implementation bug - but could be argued either way. Section 3.7.2 of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf) has this to say on the handling of unsupported input media types:

> The media type of the request entity body (if any) is a supported
>   input data format (see section 3.5). If no methods support the media
>   type of the request entity body an implementation MUST generate a
>   WebApplicationException with an unsupported media type response
>   (HTTP 415 status) and no entity. The exception MUST be processed as
>   described 4 in section 3.3.4.

So the question is, if unparseable content falls under the umbrella of "unsupported input data formats". I guess the Jersey implementation team decided it does not. So they are throwing a `WebApplicationException` ***with*** an entity body, which zips right by your exception provider:

> Instances of WebApplicationException MUST be mapped to a response as
>   follows. If the  response property of the exception does not contain
>   an entity and an exception mapping provider (see section 4.4) is
>   available for WebApplicationException an implementation MUST use the
>   provider to create a new Response instance, **otherwise the response
>   property is used directly**.

You cannot get around this, since the code is in the Jersey library itself - the most you can hope to do is argue your case in a [bug report](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY/).

Comment: Can we get around this by using `<error-page> <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type><location>/404.jsp</location> </error-page>` in web.xml?

Comment: Do you suggest we use Servlet Filters and update the Media Type?

Comment: You could try the error page solution. This interaction between the JAX-RS provider and the web container is not defined in the spec (afaik), but its worth a shot.